# Why I can't show image inside custom dialog?

Tags: android, image, dialog

I want to create some sort of logging procedure in my Android app.
I have managed to detect where user is pressing on the screen (three times) and to create logging sequence from that.
On the end, I want to show 3 images which represent selected logging sequence (from my drawable folder)

I have dynamically set drawable ID and it works when I place image on main layout.
But if I place image inside custom dialog, I get force close.
From LogCat I see following: **java.lang.NullPointerException** at       `image1.setImageResource(iIdSlike);`

If I show drawable ID as a text it's OK and ID is the same on main and custom dialog layout.

I get force close even if I set image like this (not dynamically):

```
 image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.s11);
```

Why I can't show image on custom dialog?

This is my dijalog.xml (custom dialog layout):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imgDrugi"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView01"
         android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
         android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
          />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text="Button" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TextView01"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
         android:text="@+id/TextView01" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
public class MyWorkLogiranje extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                 
                .
                .
                .               
                      //calculations to get string sPrvi


                   sPrvi="s31"; //For testing purposes sPrvi set manually          

                   //Image and text on main layout (it works)
                   iIdSlike = getResources().getIdentifier(sPrvi, "drawable", getPackageName());
                   ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPrvi);
                   image.setImageResource(iIdSlike);

                   TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPrvi);
                   text1.setText("iIdSlike: " + iIdSlike);

                   //Prikaz dijaloga

                   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyWorkLogiranje.this);
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dijalog);
                   dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
                   dialog.setCancelable(true);
                   dialog.getContext();

                   TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                   text.setText("iIdSlike: " + iIdSlike);
                   ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDrugi);
                   image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.iIdSlike);
                   //image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.s11);

                   //Podešavanje dugmeta
                   Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                   {
                       @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });   
                   dialog.show();
```

Can anyone help me with this please?
I'm scratching my head for two days about this.
Thank you.

Comment: Use ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgDrugi);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findViewById is failing. So you are getting NullPointerException.

```
 ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDrugi);
```

should be

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgDrugi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
image1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(iIdSlike));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this add this in your dialog code:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgDrugi);
```

You can use this way:

```
Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

or

This will return the id of the drawable you want to access... then you can set the image in the imageview by doing the following

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null, null);
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: I was hesitating to ask question here (after two days of reading posts) but now I see that I was wrong. Thank you all for quick and useful responses. You all rock.